# Formatting the data of a Grid-view in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am working with a GridView and I need to delete a column from that grid, I need to reorder the columns of this grid too,

I have tried a couple of solutions that I found on the internet but they do not help.

these are a couple of solutions I tried and did not work for me.

```
myGridView.columns.RemoveAt(index);    //Index is the index of the column you want to remove
myGridView.Databind();
```

and:

```
  dataGridView1.Columns[index].Visible = false; // the index of the column to be hidden
```

this is the error that shows up:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
> the collection. Parameter name: index

The code gets called from a button click and I use it to build a grid for excel exportation.

and this is my code where I filled that grid view:

```
    public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {
        ContactFormListViewModel viewModel = new ContactFormListViewModel();
        viewModel.ContactForm = contactFormRepository.GetAll();

        var gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = viewModel.ContactForm;
        gv.DataBind();
        gv.Columns[2].Visible = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DemoExcel.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
        gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);
        Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return View("Index");
    }
```

This is the code of the action method that exports the data of the grid to an excel document

Comment: `did not work for me` what does this mean? Are you getting any error? What error? Also when do you execute this code, on button click, on page_load? Is it windows application or web application?

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: `var gv = new GridView();` why are you doing this? GridView is not added to the page or Form already?

Comment: `Index was out of range.` what value of `index` you are passing in `dataGridView1.Columns[index]` ?

Comment: i am passing 2 and there are 7 columns

Comment: `myGridView`, `dataGridView1` and `gv` are the same grid view?

Comment: yes they are, there is no other grid view

Comment: Then would you mind putting proper code with one single name of gridview?Also can you tell is it windows application or web application? Are you binding gridview in page_load?

Comment: there is just one name for the gridview and it is gv, i just created a new instance of the gridview and it is a web application

Comment: Can you put entire code which first bind the gridview, then assigns value to `index` variable and then tries to remove the column from gridview. The code is bits and pieces and nothing can be figured out from it. And also please try to answer all the questions which are asked with proper details?

Comment: i posted the entire code

Comment: Thanks. If you are getting error `gv.Columns[2].Visible = false;` then you need to debug the code and check is the value of `gv.Columns.Count` you are getting.

Comment: it returns the 7

Comment: thank you for your help @Chetan Ranpariya

Comment: If you were able to solve the issue please share the solution

Comment: I have shared a solution, it is not the best solution possible but it does the work

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is enough discussion to understand the problem and I am just going to post a potential solution for this problem even if it is not the best solution.

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
        {
            ContactFormListViewModel viewModel = new ContactFormListViewModel();
            viewModel.ContactForm = contactFormRepository.GetAll();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr;
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(Int32)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Title", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstName", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LastName", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Address", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("City", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("State", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Country", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Zip", typeof(string)));

            foreach (var item in viewModel.ContactForm)
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();

                dr[0] = item.ID;
                dr[1] = item.Title;
                dr[2] = item.FirstName;
                dr[3] = item.LastName;
                dr[4] = item.Address;
                dr[5] = item.City;
                dr[6] = item.State;
                dr[7] = item.Country;
                dr[8] = item.Zip;

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            var gv = new GridView();
          
            gv.DataSource = dt;
            gv.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DemoExcel.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
            gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);
            Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

            return View("Index");
        }
```